# remove unwanted row in php array

Tags: php, json

I am displaying data from database using PHP. I am using JSON. but during result, I got unwanted array. This is sample:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";
    //$output[]=$row;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ravi Ad
    [title] => Ravi Ad
)
```

Here I saw , a extra column is displaying name [0]. i hate it and making problem in parsing . May any once can remove it ? 
i am trying this result:-

```
Array
(
    [title] => Ravi Ad
)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";
    //$output[]=$row;
    }
```

NOTE : mysql_* is deprectaed in new version of php use mysqli or PDO

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: this. or read the big red warning here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php and use PDO

Answer (score 1):

use
`mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` instead of `mysql_fetch_array($result)`

This extension is deprecated as of [PHP 5.5.0,](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include: